# protractor - how to return the boolean value using element.all

Tags: javascript, protractor

Iam a new bee to javascript , i tried to get the boolean value in side the if condition.Below are the code snippet ,

```
view.prototype.searchCustomer = function (customername) {

    var customerFound = false;
    var res = element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).count().then(function (count) {
        console.log("count of page count is " + count);
        for (var i = 1; i <= count - 4; i++) {
            element(by.xpath('//a[@class="ng-binding" and contains(text(),"rs")]'.replace("rs", i))).click();
            element(By.xpath("//div[@class='cardHeader']/a[contains(text(),'" + customername + "')]")).isPresent().then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    customerFound = true;
                    return result;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log("result is - "+customerFound);
};
```

Here console.log always returns false when the customerFound flag is true.Can any one help me on this please.I do have better knowledge on Java and learning javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't use expect() to check the isPresent()? Saving the variable and checking that with an if statement should only be done if there is a specific reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , this is a pagination expected text could be at any page.So if found i need to get the boolean value and from that value i can put an assert.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `var` to `let` in a loop:

view.prototype.searchCustomer = function (customername) {

```
let customerFound = false;
const res = element.all(by.repeater('page in pages')).count().then(function (count) {
    console.log("count of page count is " + count);
    for (let i = 1; i <= count - 4; i++) {
        element(by.xpath('//a[@class="ng-binding" and contains(text(),"rs")]'.replace("rs", i))).click();
        element(By.xpath("//div[@class='cardHeader']/a[contains(text(),'" + customername + "')]")).isPresent().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                customerFound = true;
                return result;
            }
        });
    }
});
console.log("result is - "+customerFound);
```

};